# Linking static libraries in visual studio with composite dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, static-libraries

Suppose you have two static libraries A and B such that A references methods from B.  Is it possible to statically link an executable to A and B such that there are not unresolved symbols in B referenced by A?

Here is my situation:

When I try to link everything up that way in Visual Studio 2010, there are unresolved symbols between A and B.. but not between the application and A.  The symbols it complains about have the __imp prefix (which do not, and should not, exist in B's DUMPBIN).  Why is it looking for symbols with the __imp prefix even though none of the libs are built as DLL's and I have included all of the required "Additional Library Dependencies/Directories" in all of the projects?  Also, everything is built with the exact same compiler.

EDIT:  It may be helpful to know that if library B is built as a DLL with an import library instead of a static library, everything will link up correctly.

EDIT:  I am almost certain it is not a preprocessor condition causing a declspec() or something, because there are no linker errors when the App uses B.. just when A uses B.

ANSWER:  Both Edwin and JimR are correct, there was actually a macro being used in a header causing a declspec, but I was too stubborn to notice it when they first mentioned that possibility.  Thanks guys for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the dependecies should not matter ! they may even be circular ,like A refs B and B refs A. It sounds to me (since you get linker errors) that either you don't have headerfiles for those libs (do you declare funcs from A in B by hand or funcs from B in A) or the headerfiles compile differently in your program and in your libs (due to some #define or compiler option). Do you use the same calling conventions in both prog and libs ?

Comment: I have all of the headers included and all of the methods use the same calling convention and there is no dllexport/dllimport going on.  If there was I would have expected to see A reference the __imp symbol because then it would have actually existed in B's symbol table.

Comment: you could try preprocess to a file for the offending lib and search for your symptom. This may point you directly to the problem.

Comment: Your edit means just that usage of B by lib A is different of usage of B by your program. Preprocesing to file can give you insight to what different when youre headers are included.

Comment: +1 to second comment, I would have saved a lot of time if I just did the preprocess like you suggested :)

Comment: @insipid : Glad I have been able to help

Answer (score 3):

I do not have MSVS 2010 to look at, so take this with a grain of salt.

If the symbols have *imp* in the name, that means either there's a declspec(dllimport) floating around somewhere, a (possibly embedded in the code) compiler switch forcing A to see B as a DLL or you're linking old stuff and not what's currently being produced by the build process.

Was the project you're using imported from an older version of MSVS?  I had a similar problem with a poorly managed project that was imported into MSVS 2008 a few years ago...

Either way, check A's build environment carefully and make sure you look for pragmas that embed compiler/linker switches.

Answer (score 1):

Since your used lib B as a DLL before is it possible that when you build lib A your lib B was still a DLL and when you changed lib to library you forgot to rebuild A.

Comment: +1 Good suggestion, but I have rebuilt A several times since changing B to static.

Comment: Ok ,but do you have an additional library path to your libs or do you copy your libs to a place in your lib-search-path and forgot about it. Or even both these things and there still exists an old version which is found first.